# Is wikipedia Pollard's rho algorithm for logarithms wrong?

Tags: cryptography, discrete-logarithms

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms

I am confused. It seems that algorithms's step `x ← r−1(a2i - ai) mod p` should be mod `x ← r−1(a2i - ai) mod p-1`, and with that, you cant just take the inverse as it is not obligatory for a2i-ai and p-1 be coprime. I also find that mistake in https://math.dartmouth.edu//~carlp/PDF/dltalk4.pdf so I dont who is right and who is wrong. Please help me.

Comment: can you provide concrete example of input data which shows that algorithm gives wrong result?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I'm saying that algorithm is wrong because if `x^a = x^b mod p`, it means `a = b mod p-1`, not `mod p`

Comment: so you can not give example?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski if this algorithm works can you explain me why in this case `mod p-1` and `mod p` gives the same result

Comment: no - I no deep understand the algorithm - however If you proof by example that  algorithm gives wrong results - then you get the answer to title question - this is my advice and I cannot help you in other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the $p$ in the algorithm with the usual $p$ for Discrete Logarithm in $\mathbb F_p$. For the latter you are solving
$$
a^x \equiv b \pmod p
$$
For this problem $p$ is a prime and hence if
$$
a^u \equiv a^v\pmod p
$$
then
$$
u \equiv v\pmod{p-1}
$$
But in this algorithm they assume you are solving
$$
a^x = b \in G
$$
in some cyclic group $G$ of order $p$ with generator $a$. Therefore it satisfies
$$
a^u = a^v \Longleftrightarrow u\equiv v \pmod p
$$

This algorithm is more general, since the only assumption required is that
$$<a> = \{a^1,a^2,a^3,\dots,a^p=e\}$$
generates a group of order $p$. (Where $e$ is the identity of the group.)

Comment: THANKS! I was really confused by notation...